# Automatically create a variable and set a value in a different PHP page?

Tags: php

I have some pages like a.php, b.php, c.php
Each php file has the following constructor function.

```
var database;
function __construct() {
     $database = $this->router->database;
}
```

What I want to do is:

```
function __construct() {
     $this->router->construct();
}
```

So, the construct() function in my router should create a $database variable with "$this->router->database" assigned to it. I should be able to $database->query() without any other changes in my controller.

How can I do this? It probably has a very very basic reply but I am pretty confused right now, even thinking about eval().

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are your pages a.php, b.php etc all declared as separate classes?

Comment: They're instances of the same class. All of them are using Page() class like class Page() { //startup }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit fuzzy on what you're actually trying to accomplish, but it sounds like you're trying to eliminate the duplicate constructors for all of those pages.  If that's the case, then you could create a parent class and put in the appropriate code and then inherit each of your other pages from the parent class.

```
class PageParent { 

  var $database;

  function __construct() {    
    $database = $this->router->database; 
  }

}
```

and your other files would just need

```
class Page extends PageParent
{
  function __construct() {
    /* Call parent class's constructor first... */
    parent::__construct();

    /* then add additional code here */

  }

}
```

Comment: So, anything I write in parent class is completely usable in child class? functions, variables, even construct?

Comment: Yes, but make sure you call the parent's constructor before any code in the child constructor.  See my updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what it is you want. You say that these are pages, but if you're using constructors, then you are looking at classes.  If that's the case, then it also seems like you want your class to take on the properties of the router class, and to be able to run that constructor in your class to do whatever the router constructor does.

If that's the case, what you really want to do is extend the router class.  In case you didn't know, if a class extends another class, it automatically inherits all properties and methods (i.e., variables and functions) of the parent class (i.e., the class you are extending), and lets you add new ones.  If a property or method is set as protected or public, you can even overwrite them with your own properties (though you'd better know what you're doing or you can get nasty results.)

So one example might be this:

```
class my_class extends router
{
    private $blah;
    // and so on; these can be accessed by using $this->blah in any function you like
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Your custom code, if any, goes here
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

One thing to keep in mind: if the class you want to extend is a "final" class, it cannot be extended, so you may be out of luck anyway.

For a more detailed analysis of Object Oriented Programming (AKA "OOP") works, [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) is actually quite thorough and relatively easy to understand.

Hope this helps!